# Coloring In An Outline Font In Inkscape

Tags: fonts, inkscape, image-editing

I have a specific font that I am using for a new Logo. The font is called `Dystopian Future`, and is a grungy Outline font, which looks great, but doesn't stand out against all backgrounds due to it's hollow text.

Here's what I mean:

[image]

Is there a way to color in the font part to make it a solid black?

Answer (score 3):

At least for your font, you can use the following trick which is fast but a bit rough around the edges:

#### Long version

- Select your text and duplicate it <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.
- Convert the duplicate to a path <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.
- Completely ungroup the path <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> (maybe multiple times).
- Union all paths <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (not really necessary yet, but more convenient, since you won't have to reselect the individual paths later).
- Break everything apart <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.
- Union everything <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.
- Select a color and move the new object behind the font.

#### Short version

Select the text and press
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>
<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>
<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>
Select color
<kbd>end</kbd> (yes, it's also the last step, but I mean the key.)

#### Example

Below is an example of the described method, where the created object was colored blue.
[image: Example with background]

With *rough around the edges* I meant that the scratches around the characters now also have a background. You could remove said background after the *break apart* step and before the last <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, but that would be a lot of work.

[image: rough edges]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed break down. I actually did this sort of thing by duplicating the text, and then removing the nodes(?) around each letter, but I ended up with the same `rough` edges. How exactly can I remove those scratches where you say it would be a lot of work? As this is a professional logo I obviously don't mind putting in the effort!

Comment: As described in the answer. After the break apart (ctrl+shift+k) the scratches are single objects. Selecting them with the normal mouse pointer (F1) and deleted them (del).

Comment: Ok, great. I'll try this out in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a font which is in itself outline, nor do the fonts bring an outline variant like bold or italic to experiment with.

I guess putting the text on a monochrome background, and filling it with the filling tool, is the best way to solve the problem, which would be 10 fillings for the example text.

For longer texts, or if you use it very often, maybe copying the font and changing it, might be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Type text >
with Paint bucket in default mode >
Select the letter's empty center >
turns grey >
select a color (green) from swatch >
fill turns green -